# Android: how to avoid from my process being killed

Tags: android

This may be discussed before, but i didn't find answer. I've problem with my application beeing killed when some other apps needs memory. I looked at Activity Lifecycle and tested my app. All i want to know is: when in one of my processes are called onPause() or onStop() and other apps needs memory, how to avoid from my process being killed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't avoid this. When system needs memory or does cleanup, it can kill application.

However you may somehow control importance of your application, so that it may live longer.
Read here about importance of various application parts related to process killing:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle

To have long-running application, implement Service. However, also Service may be killed, but system schedules to restart killed or crashed services after some time.

Comment: in some games, when you in midle of playing press (hard)HOME button and use some other apps, game is never killed (never noticed). how can they do this then?

Comment: It depends on Android version. On 2.3, inactive Activity is killed after some 20 minutes regardless of memory status.
Or they just properly save/restore state that you don't notice.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, every application is treated equally in android and one of the things you have to consider is that your app might be killed. You can keep services running, that might do what you want if it's something in the background.